# Java Eclipse Hebrew word order reversed

Tags: java, eclipse, hebrew

Hi I am a student using Eclipse for school and when trying to write in Hebrew, but it writes words in the reverse order that I wrote them in.
For example:

**correct order:** `System.out.println("הזן מספר שלילי");`

**what eclipse writes:** `System.out.println("שלילי מספר הזן");`

I have tried changing the settings in Window > Preferences > General > Globalization and it didn't change anything... any ideas that I can try?

Comment: it would no doubt be easier to add a method that reverses that input. How is Eclipse supposed to 'know' whether you are entering it in the right or reversed order? How is eclipse supposed to determine that this order isn't exactly how you want it?

Comment: I don't actually know how to add a method I'm quite new to eclipse but for example in other pcs the eclipse displays the text in the right order...

Comment: Hebrew is written from right to left, right? So what exactly happens when typing Hebrew characters in Eclipse? Is the second Hebrew character displayed to the left or right of the first Hebrew character? How is the character order in the file? Is it different than displayed in Eclipse in the Java editor? And when running it, what is printed in Eclipse in the Console view vs. what on the command line?

Comment: The words are okay on themselves they are written correctly but the order of them is reversed...

Comment: @HenZrihen adding a method has nothing to do with eclipse, it's the basics of the Java language. If you don't know the basics of the language, using a professional IDE won't make your work progress any faster

Comment: I'm a student learning java in school and they told us to use eclipse please don't assume stuff that doesn't have anything to do with my original question!

Comment: @HenZrihen It's unclear to me what do you mean by _"written"_ (displayed, printed, or ...?) and where it is reversed and where not. That's why I asked. Could you please answer my questions one by one?

Comment: I guess the issue is that the Eclipse text editors does not support the [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) which is used in HTML for that. See also [_"Due to the bidi algorithm, a source code editor may not display character entities or numeric character references as expected."_](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html).

Comment: Is there any fix to this because when my friends use it on their pc it doesn't reverse order

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bidi.html

Comment: 1. when writing in the java editor it displays the Hebrew words in reverse order, and it does happen too in the console (see here:https://imgur.com/iRmMF25)

Comment: 2. I tried multiple times enabling bidirectional support and it didn't change anything perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: 3. When my friends using the same Eclipse version try to write in Hebrew both in Java editor and in the console it displays the words correctly in the correct order!